# SoapUI test execution returns error "The directory name is invalid"

Tags: tfs, soapui, artifactory

I have an established CI pipeline comprising (prior to deployment):

- TFS build
- JFrog Artifactory for build artifact management
- SoapUI and SpecFlow (BDD & itaretive, parameterised) for web service functional test automation

I have no access to our build agent servers and no permission to install  anything thereon. Instead, I've added the SoapUI binaries as links to my functional test project; the binaries are pulled from source control in the Get Sources step of every build.

This works okay but it greatly increases the footprint of my test project (and any other test project for which SoapUI would be required), and by extension, the execution time of the build: functional testing will only execute on a small fraction of the builds executed (only if application codebase has changed or sufficient time interval since last full build and test has elapsed).

For these reasons, I opted to remove the SoapUI binaries folder from my test project and instead deploy a SoapUI binaries zip archive to an Artifactory repository. With the addition of a PowerShell script step in my build definition, I can pull the SoapUI binaries as needed and extract to the desired location on the build server. Foolishly, I thought this might be straightforward...

I did manage to push the zipped SoapUI binaries folder to the Artifactory repo, and, in my Development build definition, I did manage to correctly script my PowerShell step to pull the zip archive and extract its content successfully to he same folder in the build binaries directory on the build agent server as it had been located originally.

However, when I execute my build, in the step where the SoapUI tests are executed, on the first test iteration, I see the following error returned to build console:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid

I added a PowerShell scripted filtered folder content step before the test execution step in both my **Development** (new) and my **Production** (original) builds for comparison. **Both show the required 'testrunner.bat' to be present, in the same folder on the build agent server**.
The test project itself has been unchanged (except for the removal of the SoapUI binaries folder).

To summarise:
I'm trying to execute SoapUI tests in two builds; in each build, the same test project is used and the SoapUI binaries are in the same location when the test execution kicks off.
One build executes successfully without issue.
One build fails at test execution step, returning error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid".

I'm very puzzled by this; insights and SoapUI wisdom most welcome.
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, there was a discrepancy in the directory paths on the testrunner.bat between the builds; a '_' where a '-' should have been